# Very slow application loading after logging into Pop!_OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, pop-os

I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (standalone single-boot) on my Ryzen 7 2700X with 32GB RAM and a GeForce RTX 2070.

My startup drive is a Samsung EVO 960 NVMe.

I am getting onto the login screen perfectly fine in ~10-15s, however after logging in it takes at least 30 to 60 seconds for any autostart application (e.g., Signal, Discord etc.) to start up, before that, I can barely do anything but have a look at my desktop background.

Here's my `systemd-analyze blame` output:

```
4.164s plymouth-quit-wait.service
3.495s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
1.083s gpu-manager.service
 683ms fwupd.service
 679ms accounts-daemon.service
 655ms vboxdrv.service
 592ms user@1000.service
 436ms libvirtd.service
 295ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap.service
 237ms dev-nvme0n1p3.device
 236ms networkd-dispatcher.service
 205ms networking.service
[...]
```

It doesn't show anything unusual.

`sudo dmesg` output:

```
[   10.548231] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   10.656251] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp24s0: link becomes ready
[   11.134857] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   18.335003] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   27.875643] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   57.857499] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00001f00] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

There's a 30s gap between rfkill and some weird NVIDIA DRM error of which however I'm not sure if it's the reason (I already tried downgrading the NVIDIA GPU driver from 525 to 515).

How can I monitor the startup process to find out what takes my Pop!_OS installation so long to start up?

I also tried `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`, however it mainly gives me output of `PackageKit`, `pop-upgrade` and `flatpak-1.desktop`.

Automatic updates are already turned off.

Does anyone have an idea about how to speed up the boot process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue here, I have a loaded system: 32 gb ram, i7, nvidia 2070 takes almost 90 seconds for anything to load immediately after logging in.

Comment: @JimmyJohnson happy to hear I'm not the only one facing this issue. Haven't solved it till now though. Fun fact: my notebook with a similar setup doesn't have that problem so I suppose it's an application problem.

Comment: @JimmyJohnson I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the solution was as easy as stupid: after moving my /home partition from an HDD to an NVMe, the startup process takes 4s.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).